# Trouble with polymorphic function type with multiple optional arguments

Tags: flowtype

I'm trying to add types to a library with multiple optional parameters. This is best described in the flowtype.org/try link below:

https://flowtype.org/try/#0CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtXwGcQJwMcYBRAD3GQxAB4AlAPgAoAoeQ408ggFyEMMLKgDm8AD7wAgjBhQAngwIix4lgBou8NrwC2IVBkFyFyhlFRLt8AHSO4aoQG0AugEp4AXhbwmHW5He2cMN3cOTyEmAG4ODlBIWAQUdGw8HhJMcmpaegZZLQD2XSJsshgzNVEJaXNFFRqNbV19EiMTM3lGqxs7KCEihycQF3gPbz8AoPhBuVng0fGPKJj4jgB6TfgASXgQKgAHUngMAAssAjOceCOsMABrM-OEADcQKtx8TIgxBAALBxynxKDQwHQQGwAORQAjARDQ4rtECdUxTfyGYymewkCQXTzxEE5MH5KGw+GI5FYrrFVDIAwYg4dbEEXHGcQXeAAang9IMxQAzISOEA

I'm having trouble getting flow to pick between the two polymorphic types. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, figured it out. Turns out I didn't need to overload. I can just do

```
declare function selectorExecute<A, B, C, D, E, F, R>(
  selectors: string | Array<string>,
  (elements: Array<any>, a: A, b: B, c: C, d: D, e: E, f: F, ...rest: []) => R,
  a: A, b: B, c: C, d: D, e: E, f: F,
  ...rest: []
): R;
```